# Unificationegine not working with instagarm sharing

Tags: unification, unificationengine

I am getting this error when using unificationegine in php and in CURL

```
$app = new UEApp("590f402bd2a043f98823eb1964230b2ab","a62c855ae17b5c7acb2345fabfbcc3a93");
$user = new UEUser("039c8b4b-58f6-46f6-b872-fsdc71e57eda", "91892138-e549-41c9-98ea-4db790c3d416");
$con = $access_token."@instagram.com/?username=rajneesh8329&password=testing23";
$connection = $user->add_connection("instagramBoard", "instagram", $con);
return $connection;
$options = array(
    "receivers" => array(
        array(
            "name"=> "Me"
        )
    ),
    "message"=>array(
        "subject"=>"Transparentcom testing fine",
        "body"=> "Testing",
        "image"=> 'http://politibits.blogs.tuscaloosanews.com/files/2010/07/sanford_big_dummy_navy_shirt.jpg',
        "link"=>array(
            "uri"=> '',
            "description"=> "",
            "title"=>"Click here for view"
        )
    )
);
//Send the message and get their uris
$uris = $connection->send_message($options);
$shareKeys = explode('/', $uris[0]);
return $shareKeys[3];
```

Error:

**Exception in UEUser.php line 74: The password you entered is incorrect. Please try again.**

This is very big problem when I am using CURL then getting same error

```
{"Status":{"instagram":{"status":417,"info":"417 Connector returned error: 500 I
nternal Server Error: "}},"URIs":[]}
```

Comment: please use this ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42502740/unification-not-providing-me-user-password-and-username/45409365#45409365

Answer (score 0):

We could see that you can now specify optional parameters while you add a connection.

The optional params for each connections are specified in documentation under 'Add connection' section https://developer.unificationengine.com/ In case of intagram, the optional params are "username" and "password".

With the updated version of SDK (https://github.com/unifiedinbox/ue-php-sdk), we are able to post to instagram.

Comment: Yes, I have resolved this issue, but as per unification document only username and password required but its working with some extra things like usename,passowrd@instagram then its working.